# Enabling developer mode on cash machine

Tags: usb-debugging

[image]What I have is a cash register machine with a preinstalled custom launcher and Android 7.0

How to access the developer options and connect via adb? There is no settings menu with well known "build number"

I tried switching to recovery mode, but it didn't help me - it shows "no command"

Comment: Have you tried fastboot? Then you can flash a custom recovery and access ADB.

Comment: Thanks I tried it after your advice
Tried to execute `fastboot oem unlock`, or `fastboot flash unlock`
But got an error on device that unlock operation is not allowed